# Print comment form inside node's page instead of a link to comment page

Tags: 6, theming, forms, comments

How can I print comment form inside node's page instead of a link to comment page (Drupal 6) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that under "Comment settings" on the edit page of your content type.

[image]